# Does wxWidget support Stylesheets like Qt does?

Tags: wxwidgets, stylesheet

I would like to know if wxWidget support stylesheets or even styling widgets like Qt does.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

wxWidgets uses native widgets, so it only supports CSS if the underlying platform does. In practice, this means that it supports them when using GTK+ (so that any user-defined themes using GTK-specific CSS work correctly for wxWidgets applications), but not the other platforms (but Windows themes still work correctly for wxWidgets applications -- they're just not using CSS).

Answer (score 0):

No : it doesn't.
wxWidgets uses natives controls only.

But it supports "skinning" using owner-drawn controls.

Regards
Xav'

Comment: Could you explain further what "skinning" means?